# Using EditButton(), I am unable to delete rows

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a tabview in a navigation view. I added an edit button in a toolbar view modifier.

My problem is that when I click on the edit button, only the done button replace the edit button. I can't delete rows but there is a little swipe effect on rows.

My View :

```
struct MemeMeMemesView: View {
    var viewModel = MemeMeViewModel()
    
    @State private var selection = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                TableViewMemes(viewModel: viewModel)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                    }
                    .tag(0)
                GridViewMemes(viewModel: viewModel)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "square.grid.3x3")
                    }
                    .tag(1)
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Sent Memes"), displayMode: .inline)
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
            .padding(.top)
        }
    }
}

struct TableViewMemes: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MemeMeViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.memes, id: \.content) { meme in
                TableViewMeme(meme: Image(meme.imgName), content: meme.content)
            }

            .onDelete(perform: viewModel.deleteMeme)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel :

```
class MemeMeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    static var memes = [
        MemeMeModel.Meme(imgName: "thumbnail", content: "HELLO WORLD!"),
        MemeMeModel.Meme(imgName: "thumbnail2", content: "YO BOY!")
    ]
    
    @Published private var model: MemeMeModel = MemeMeModel(memes: memes)
    
    var memes: Array<MemeMeModel.Meme> {
        model.memes
    }
    
    // MARK: - Intent
    
    func deleteMeme(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        model.deleteMeme(at: offsets)
    }
}
```

Comment: ForEach builds a list from a collection. You sure, you want embed this list into `List`? Also, having a TabView _within_ a NavigationView seems unusual at best - but possible. You may have your TabView as the container for several views which then have a NavigationView.

Comment: But doing this way will show the tabview when using navigationlink.

Comment: Ah, I see - you need ForEach to apply the `onDelete` modifier. My fault!

Comment: It would help to see `MemeMeViewModel`

Comment: So, you use a TabView to group two lists rendering one of them, and then apply the listStyle modifier. OK one can do this. You may use a simple switch statement here as well.
Can you show the view model, please. I think, from the looking at the views, it seems to be OK.

Comment: I updated the post (added the view model)

Answer (score 0):

Pleas try the following code . I think you didn't have set you array as @published.

```
struct MemeMeMemesView: View {
    var viewModel = MemeMeViewModel()
    
    @State private var selection = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                TableViewMemes(viewModel: viewModel)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                    }
                    .tag(0)
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Sent Memes"), displayMode: .inline)
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
            .padding(.top)
        }
    }
}

class MemeMeViewModel : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var memes = ["onw","two","three"]
    
    func deleteMeme(_ index : IndexSet){
        
        if let first = index.first {
            memes.remove(at: first)
        }
    }
}

struct TableViewMemes: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MemeMeViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.memes, id: \.self) { meme in
                    Text(meme)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: viewModel.deleteMeme)
        }
    }
}
```